# How to eliminate ring distortion in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

I am trying to draw a molecule with two connecting pentagonal rings. This is what I have so far:

```
\begin{figure}
\chemfig{
    O=_[1,,]*5([::-45]-O-Cu*5([::-72]-NH_2--(=^[1,,]O)-O-)-NH_2--)
}
\caption{\textit{trans}-bisglycinatocopper(II)}
\label{fig:trans-bisglycinatocopper(II)}
\end{figure}
```

Which gives me:

[image: molecule with distorted ring]

I try to fix it by adding `[,,1]` to the bond after NH2:

```
\begin{figure}
\chemfig{
    O=_[1,,]*5([::-45]-O-Cu*5([::-72]-NH_2-[,,1]-(=^[1,,]O)-O-)-NH_2--)
}
\caption{\textit{trans}-bisglycinatocopper(II)}
\label{fig:trans-bisglycinatocopper(II)}
\end{figure}
```

Which gives me:

[image: molecule with overlapping bond]

I understand that in the notation `[,,1]`, `1` is the atom of departure for the bond.

How do I get the ring to be a regular pentagon, while also preventing the bond from overlapping the formula?

Answer (score 6):

I figured it out, the options for the bond has a fourth option. I needed to add `[,,,2]` to the bond preceding NH2 to indicate that it should connect to the second atom:

```
\begin{figure}
\chemfig{
    O=_[1,,]*5([::-45]-O-Cu*5([::-72]-[,,,2]H_2N-[,,2]-(=^[1,,]O)-O-)-NH_2--)
}
\caption{\textit{trans}-bisglycinatocopper(II)}
\label{fig:trans-bisglycinatocopper(II)}
\end{figure}
```

[image: fixed ring with no distortion]

Take a look at the "Departure and Arrival Atoms" section of [this](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf) documentation.